# Get the source table information for views

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the source table information for each views from a particular schema in snowflake.
I have tried as follows and both works. The first command list the number of views from a particular schema and second one is to get the reference source table for the same with a hard coded value.
I am trying to write a loop and hence for each view, I would like to get the source table names and other informations. Thanks.

```
   SELECT *
FROM test.information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'VIEW'
  AND table_schema = 'BALLS';
 

select * from table(get_object_references(database_name=>'test', schema_name=>'BALLS', object_name=>'test_View'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use snowflake scripting to quickly write for loop and write results to table. Below is sample code.

```
begin
    let view_cur cursor for SELECT *
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_type = 'VIEW'
          AND table_schema = 'PUBLIC';

    create or replace table view_source_details (DATABASE_NAME varchar,
                        SCHEMA_NAME varchar,    OBJECT_NAME varchar,    
                        REFERENCED_DATABASE_NAME varchar,REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME varchar,    
                        REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME varchar,REFERENCED_OBJECT_TYPE varchar); 

    for view_det in view_cur
        do
        let sql varchar := 'insert into view_source_details
            select * from table(get_object_references(database_name=>'''||view_det.TABLE_CATALOG||'''
            , schema_name=>'''||view_det.TABLE_SCHEMA||''', object_name=>'''||view_det.TABLE_NAME||'''))';
        execute immediate :sql;
            end for ;
    return 'all view details captured in table view_source_details';

end;

select * from view_source_details;
```

Comment: Thanks and it works. Could you please let me know how to catch exception?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions